# Styling for an HTML table from database

Tags: php, html, css

**I need to make the results of the query that appears in the table to look like the layout prototype showing below.**

I just want to know how to make the **picture** on the left. And **Sandwich Name** and the **Price** to be lined up on top and the **description** under it.

[image]

I'm using foreach to echo the query in a table.

```html
foreach ($rows as $row)
                {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td><img src=" . $row["image_file"] . "></td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["productname"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["description"] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row["price"] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
```

**Mine currently showing this:**
[image]

Comment: This will not work : `echo "<td><img src=" . $row["image_file"] . "></td>";`  should be `echo "<td><img src=\"" . $row["image_file"] ."\"></td>";`

Comment: @moskito-x It's actually working as you can see up in the picture, you're code is better than mine thank you for the note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:
nested tables,
rowspan, or
css

It all depends on what you want.

Rowspan

```
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td rowspan='2'><img src='" . $row["image_file"] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["productname"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["price"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";    
    echo "<td colspan='2'>" . $row["description"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to echo every row and you need to escape whichever quotes your are using in HTML vs PHP. For a sample of how this could be done...

```
<?php
$rows = array(array('image_file' => "1", 'productname' => 't', 'description' => 'scription', 'price' => '1'));
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>' .
    '<td><img src="'. $row["image_file"] . '"></td>'.
    '<td>' . $row["productname"] . '</td>'.
    '<td>' . $row["description"] . '</td>' .
    '<td>' . $row["price"] . '</td>'.
    '</tr>';
}
```

Output:

```
<tr><td><img src="1"></td><td>t</td><td>scription</td><td>1</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way, by means of CSS and not nested tables:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Image</td>
  <td>
    <header><h2>Italian</h2><h3>7.99€</h3></header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero neque adipisci, necessitatibus dicta provident voluptates, laboriosam asperiores ratione eveniet. Perspiciatis doloribus, ducimus non architecto ut laudantium, at necessitatibus nulla voluptatum.</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And

```
h2 {
  float:left;
}
h3 {
  float:right;
}
header:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

You can play the result in this pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXNomR

With your PHP code, it would be:

```
foreach ($rows as $row){
  echo "<tr>
          <td><img src=".$row["image_file"]."></td>
          <td>
            <header>
              <h2>".$row["productname"]."</h2>
              <h3>".$row["price"]."</h3>  
            </header>
            <p>".$row["description"]."</p>
          </td>
         </tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS fload element instead of table element

```
<div style="display:block">
    <img style="width:300px;height:300px;fload:left" />
    <div class="detail" style="width:600px;height:300px;fload:left">
        <div class="title" style="width:600px;height:50px">
           <div class="name" style="width:500px;height:50px;float:right">
              Food name
           </div>
           <div class="price" style="width:100px;height:50px;float:right">
              Price
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
           Description
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```